# css vertical align help

Tags: html, css

I'm using a strict doctype and cannot get one of my divs aligned to the bottom. I'd like to specify a 100% height on the parent container and then push the inner container to the floor of the parent. How is this done using a strict doctype?

This is the parent: -- Works as expected. At 100% height

```
#content_left {
vertical-align:top;
padding:0;
margin:0;
min-width:195px;
color:#fff;
height:100%;
}
```

This is the inner div: doesnt work

```
.sidebarmenu {
position:relative;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to use absolute positioning and specify `bottom: 0`:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: your suggestion didn't do anything at all Marcus.

Comment: You will have to give some more detail regarding your code in your question, since assuming a `position: relative` parent of fixed height, that should have worked.

Comment: No Marcus, I said that I needed a 100% height. The parent container will expand or contract depending on the page content. All I want to do is push this div to the floor regardless of what the content height makes the page

Comment: Basically all the parent needs is a defined height, and not one specified by the children it contains. Thus a 100% height is just as good as a fixed height. As before we will need more information in order to understand why this is't working in your particular case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I agree with you. I was thinking that a strict doctype would prevent the 100% height and may be my problem. Could this be the case?

Comment: No, I use strict doc types all the time, strict basically just means that none of the old HTML tags can be used in this document.

Comment: OK, that's a good thing then. Boy, css really makes my life difficult. I really am considering a table design instead.

Comment: table designs are the worst thing you could ever do (it terms of flexibility) there are things you just cannot do in a table design.

Comment: I know but this is outright ridiculous; something that used to be so simple takes hours to troubleshoot in css. I just set a border on my parent container and the 100% min-height isn't doing anything. It stops at the bottom of the bottom most element and there is a lot of space left under it.

Comment: use `height` not `min-height`. Plus this also relies upon the sidebars parent having a height of 100% as well.

Comment: Maybe the sidebar doesn't have a height of 100%. I'll check that and come back. Thanks for all the help Marcus

Comment: Marcus, I'm going to edit my post with what I have. The parent div is working as expected but the inner div will not expand

Comment: Marcus, I don't know what the heck I did but the inner div is past the bottom of the parent div. Is there a way to get it to rest on the bottom of the parent div?

Comment: I used position:absolute but that won't work because as the page grows and shrinks, the inner content div doesn't grow/shrink with it.

Comment: That would probably be because you set the inner div to a height of 100% and then added padding which will increase the height further.

Comment: Marcus, the inner div has no padding. I have the height set to 195px. The parent div has the 100% height but it still isn't working. I really appreciate all of your help and efforts and will credit you for the answer but I'm chucking css and going back to tables. This is crazy and I have other things I need to focus on. Seriously, thanks for all of your help!

Comment: I think you need to just take a look at a basic css position tutorial. Its really quite simple once you get to understanding it. I think your table mindset might be clouding your actions.

Comment: It could very well be. Let me ask you a question. I'm sure that you have table design experience so you should be able to answer this. What is so great about css when it requires a bunch of hacks to make it work cross browser and tables works in all browsers? Lynx not included in that..

Comment: @jim: if you could post your working table code somewhere, that’d be great: might be easier to see what you’re trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying:

```
#content {position:relative;bottom:0;}
```

Comment: That would just move the #content element 0 pixels downwards I think

Comment: Mark, this didn't do anything. Am I correct to have a height of 100% in the parent?

Comment: try set #content to position:absolute;bottom:0;
yes, 100% in parent should be fine...

Comment: OK Mark, I have `.menu {height:900px;}` and `#content {position:absolute;bottom:0;}` but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Discussing layout issues in text can be tricky, but note that you’ve said you want a `<div>` aligned to the bottom, but you’ve not said to the bottom of *what*.

I think you mean the bottom of the browser window. Unfortunately, you can’t really do this in CSS: the root element is always as tall as its content requires, and not as tall as the browser window (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Hey Paul, thanks for the hand here. I have a sidebar menu that is inside of other elements. The sidebar element has a height of 100%. I want the `<div>` aligned to the bottom of the sidebar, not the bottom of the page. Is this not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure why it won't work. I just set a border on the parent div that has a 100% height but the border isn't 100%. It's only as tall as the last item in the parent div.

Comment: That is what 100% tall means. As high as the parent element.

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing that now. :)  There are 2 divs. The parent has a height of 100% and the border verifies that it is at 100%. The inner div however has a height of 100% but will not expand below the bottom of the bottom most element. I'll post in my OP what I have

Comment: @jim: bit confused by the new code you’ve posted, and what you want it to do. `.sidebarmenu` is the child of `#content_left`, and is set to `height: 100%`. Do you want it to be as tall as `#content_left` then? If so, set `#content_left` to `position: relative`, and `.sidebarmenu` to `position: absolute`, as here: http://www.pauldwaite.co.uk/test-pages/4212933/